# Strict inclusions $H^{1/2}\subsetneq\operatorname{vmo}\subsetneq \operatorname{bmo}$ on $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis

I want to verify that 
$$H^{1/2}(S^1,S^1)\subsetneq \operatorname{vmo}(S^1,S^1) \subsetneq \operatorname{bmo}(S^1,S^1)=L^1(S^1,S^1)$$
Where vmo and bmo are the spaces of vanishing and bounded mean oscillation like [here](http://www.mat.ufpb.br/jmbo/papers/Brezis/brezis/brenir95.pdf) and $H^{1/2}$ is the sobolev-space $W^{1/2,2}$.

The inclusions $H^{1/2}\subset\operatorname{vmo}\subset \operatorname{bmo}$ are clear for me, but why are holding the inequalities?

Thank you,
Maxi

Comment: does no one have an idea?

Comment: Hi, I am new to Sobolev Spaces, what is your definition of $H^{1/2}$ and $W^{1/2, 2}$ here precisely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the first inclusion is strict, start with a Weierstrass function $f:S^1\to\mathbb R$
$$f(e^{i\theta})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}\sin(4^n\theta).$$

The Fourier coefficients satisfy $\sum_p|\hat f(p)|<\infty$ but $\sum_p|p\hat f(p)|^2=\infty.$ This ensures that $f$ is continuous hence in $\mathrm{VMO}(S^1),$ but not in $H^{1/2}(S^1).$ To get the codomain in $S^1$ we can take $f+i\sqrt{1-f^2}$ which will still be continuous - this uses $|f|\leq 1.$

To show the second inclusion is strict take
$$g(e^{i\theta})=\begin{cases}
1&(0\leq \theta<\pi)\\
-1&(-\pi\leq \theta<2\pi).
\end{cases}$$

This is bounded hence in $\mathrm{BMO}(S^1,S^1),$ but the mean oscillation in an interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ is $1$ so $g$ is not in $\mathrm{VMO}(S^1,S^1).$